# Global seek bar MediaElement wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement, seekbar

How to create global seek bar for audio player in WP7?I want create something like this [image: http://fastandroid.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vkontakte-amberfog_4.png]

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: How I can realize this?I ask for even realize of this, not code. For the first I add  `var _pop = new Popup { Child = mediaelelement, IsOpen = true };` and I can play audio on all pages

Answer (score 0):

Add the necessary controls to the application frame, rather than a/each page.

In app.xaml add something like this:

```
<Application.RootVisual>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationFrame x:Name="RootFrame"
           Navigated="CompleteInitializePhoneApplication"
           NavigationFailed="RootFrame_NavigationFailed">
        <phone:PhoneApplicationFrame.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="700"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ClientArea">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        // your controls here
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </phone:PhoneApplicationFrame.Template>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationFrame>
</Application.RootVisual>
```

Comment: I need to do it in App.xaml.cs?
Please give me right direction where I can find materials about it.

Comment: @wsevendays. doing it in app.xaml will be easiest. See updated answer

Comment: I can't get it works. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6j0Vu0mvrNo
...`<ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
              <Button Content="hello" Height="100" Width="300"/>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>`...